# Zoneminder camera permanently idle

Tags: camera, surveillance, zoneminder

I have an Ubuntu server with [zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) installed.  I only have one camera (cheap Logitech USB model) and it seems to be permanently idle.

I'm also getting this error repeatedly in the logs

```
06/06/2010 08:26:56.563783 zmwatch[28234].INF [Restarting capture daemon for main_room, shared memory not valid]
06/06/2010 08:26:56.812964 zmwatch[28234].INF ['zmc -d /dev/video0' starting at 10/06/06 08:26:56, pid = 29214]
06/06/2010 08:27:06.814486 zmwatch[28234].INF [Restarting capture daemon for main_room, shared memory not valid]
06/06/2010 08:27:07.054854 zmwatch[28234].INF ['zmc -d /dev/video0' starting at 10/06/06 08:27:07, pid = 29219]
```

I've already tried following the [instructions in the FAQ](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#What_does_a_.27Can.27t_shmget:_Invalid_argument.27_error_in_my_logs_mean.3F_and_my_cameras_won.27t_display_video_at_higher_resolutions.) for increasing shared memory, but that doesn't seem to work.  What do I need to do to get this working?

**Note:** I have tested the camera with Linux via [Cheese](http://projects.gnome.org/cheese/), and that works fine.

Comment: Can you post your Zoneminder camera config, `sysctl kernel.shmmax` output and `lsusb -v` output relevant to camera? Let the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) help you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but maybe trying [Motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/twiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) and seeing if that works could reveal some more information that might help you zoom in on the problem?